# TeXShop is not auto-completing \ref{...} commands with labels using F5 any more?

Tags: texshop, auto-completion

In TeXShop, I used to use F5 to suggest auto-completions for \ref{ } commands, for example, \ref{fig: ... and then pressing F5 would list all the fig:... labels I had assigned for me to choose from. Today, it wasn't listing any of the labels. And selecting labels from the list of labels just took me to where the label is in the source document.

Pushing F5 lists citation from BibDesk just like normal, but none of the labels.

Did something change in TeXShop? What should I be doing to get a list of labels that I can select from? (I've got a lot of figures in this paper...)

I'm running TeXShop Version 4.70, BibDesk Version 1.8.8 (5799), and TeXLive 2016.

Comment: I'm running 4.70 too, but see no change. If you have a lot of labels in a document it sometimes takes some time to produce the list.

Answer (score 0):

I encounter same issue with auto-completion of `\cite{}` command. Seems like sometimes it works, sometimes not.

The only **solution** I found, is to quit TeXshop and recompiling file, which is absolutely not satisfying.

Comment: BTW: Welcome to this place.